# Using SqlBulkCopy with datatable to insert excell records

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am trying to use SqlBulkCopy woth the datatable to insert data in to database

I have this code

```
 string mydemo="my demo record";
        DataTable prodSalesData = new DataTable("ProductSalesData");

        // Create Column 1: SaleDate
        DataColumn dateColumn = new DataColumn();
        dateColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
        dateColumn.ColumnName = "SaleDate";

        prodSalesData.Columns.Add(dateColumn);


        DataRow dailyProductSalesRow = prodSalesData.NewRow();
        dailyProductSalesRow["SaleDate"] = mydemo;


        // Create DbDataReader to Data Worksheet
        using (OleDbDataReader dr1 = command1.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // Bulk Copy to SQL Server
            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy1 = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
            {

                bulkCopy1.DestinationTableName = "activity1";
                bulkCopy1.ColumnMappings.Add(0, "id");
                bulkCopy1.ColumnMappings.Add(1,"name");
                bulkCopy1.ColumnMappings.Add(2, "activity1first");
                bulkCopy1.ColumnMappings.Add(3, "activity1second");
                bulkCopy1.ColumnMappings.Add(4, prodSalesData.Columns.ToString());
                bulkCopy1.WriteToServer(dr1);

            }
        }
```

Here  fors 4 recods comes frome xcell file but i want to insert an external data to the same table , i tried this much but it gives me this error

```
The given ColumnMapping does not match up with any column in the source or destination.
```

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error is triggered because you are setting the mappinng for 4 prodSalesData columns (by position) but you only have one column. The ColumnMappings should contain the columns being mapped from the source to the destination i.e.

```
bulkCopy1.ColumnMappings.Add("SaleDate", prodSalesData.Columns.ToString());
```